# Import / Export to CSV Web Scraper - Merge HTTP with CSV data

Tags: python, pandas, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This works fine and as intended. However, I would like to make it a bit easier for usage on other sites. It currently pulls the https address for NFTs on solana explorer from a CSV file and grabs specific data from these NFTs and then writes it to a new CSV file, including the original Https address.  I would like to remove the https from excel and leave only the mint address of the NFTS.

For example, Currently in the CSV its website.com/nft/xyz0123456789yutmererereieirebngT
I would like it so its just xyz0123456789yutmererereieirebngT in the excel file that it reads from and then in the code I'd like to have

website = https://website/nft

and then combine that with the part it reads from in the code. But, I'm not sure exactly how to implement it.

I also keep getting multiple errors from each read due to the chrome driver
error: USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning.

I downgraded the driver to exact version Chrome using and still got it. I then downloaded an earlier version of the driver and it worked fine on the first run and no errors popped out. However, on subsequent runs the errors came back. So, not sure how to proceed in removing those errors as well. The script still pulls the scraped info and exports it to CSV, so it's just an eyesore rather than causing problems with the script. Either way would love any input on how to make that disappear. Chrome version is Version 103.0.5060.134 (Official Build) (64-bit)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
import pandas as pd
import re



def scrape(url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Path\to\driver\chromedriver.exe")    
    driver.get(url)
    sleep(5)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")    
    data = ([i.text for i in soup.select("h2.header-title")])
    content = str(data)
    rawdata = re.sub('[^0-9,.]', '', content)
    print(rawdata)
    return rawdata
    driver.quit()

df = pd.read_csv('scrape.csv')
for x in df.values:
    index = df[df['URL'] == x[0]].index.item()
    df.at[index, 'MINT'] = scrape(x[0])

 df.to_csv('scraped.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: `'website.com/nft/xyz0123456789yutmererereieirebngT'.split('/')[-1]`

Comment: Not from excel. In excel I've already removed https. In excel its just the mint address now. I need to create a variable for http to merge into the section for x in df.values